# How to fix "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'" using numpy.where() with python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv table with many columns, including a column named "blend" and a column named "hires."
Blend has elements like 'N', 'Y unpub NAME', and 'Y? unnpub NAME.'
Hires has elements like 'N', 'redo;NAME OF TELESCOPE', and 'NAME OF TELESCOPE.'

I want a list (called 'known_binary') where the following conditions are true: blend=='Y' & hires!='N' & hires!='redo'.
(I'll be making other lists with other combinations of those possibilities like a list where: blend=='Y?' & (hires=='N' | hires=='redo').

I know how to have python just look at either the first letter of the element, or first four letters, etc..
(for example, this works without error):

```
redo = np.where([x[0:4]=='redo' for x in hires])[0]
```

But, when I put multiple things in np.where() it doesn't work:

```
file = pandas.read_csv('file location')
blend = file["blend"]
hires = file["hires"]


known_binary = np.where(([x[0]=='Y' for x in blend]) & ([x[0]!='N' for x in hires]) & ([x[0:4]!='redo' for x in hires]))[0]
```

I get the error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'"

I just want a list of indices (might be the wrong wording, sorry) where the conditions I stated are true.

If the elements in the hires column (for example) were just "redo" and not "redo;name of specific telescope" I wouldn't be having any issue.

I know how to do some specific stuff in python for astronomy, but overall I have VERY little understanding of how all of this stuff works.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This use of `&` works numpy arrays, but not for lists.

Comment: Why don't you do `np.where(file['blend'].eq('Y')& file['hire'].eq('N')&file['hire'].str[:4].ne('redo'))`

Comment: @QuangHoang I'll give that a try

Comment: @QuangHoang np.where(blend.str[:2].eq('Y ') & hires.ne('N') & hires.str[:4].ne('redo')) seems to work. (I can't just put file['blend'].eq('Y') because the element is "Y other stuff" not just "Y".) THANK YOU!

Comment: Then you can do `blends.str[0].eq('Y')`.